# Does Visual Studio Express 2015 supports Windows Store Apps?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-express

I'm trying to run a solution by double click on the .sln file and an error message appear:

> The following project are not supported by either this edition of visual studio or the version of windows installed on this computer....

According the book i'm working with, the .sln runs great on VS Express for windows desktop 2012& Windows 8.
In my computer i'm running Windows 10 and VS Express for windows desktop 2015.
The .csproj contain the line

```
<ProjectGuid>{B73C2F01-B48F-4D86-8F43-37A24023F66A}</ProjectGuid>
```

I realized that it means Windows Store Apps. Doesn't Visual Studio Express 2015 supports Windows Store Apps? If the answer is "No" that means that the book delivers wrong information (as i had already said, the book author says that the solution runs great on the Express Desktop version).

Comment: I didn't think there was such a thing as the Express edition for 2015... there's the *Community* edition... are you sure you're not running VS2014 Express?

Comment: This may be relevant:https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-2015-compatibility-vs.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet There still is an Express edition: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx

Comment: Ooh, interesting. I'd just go for Community at this point :)

Comment: Is it possible that the specific "VS express for windows desktop 2012" version was updated the way that in the beginning it supported windows store app and during the development of the 2012 version it stopped support this type of projects?

Answer (score 3):

> VS Express for **windows desktop** 2015

For Windows *desktop* means you can make desktop apps (aka Win32).

To make Windows store (UWP/WinRT) apps, you can download the [Community](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691978&clcid=0x409) or the [Express for Windows](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691987&clcid=0x409) edition